# System Error/Success messages are not displaying in custom theme

Tags: magento2

I have created a simple custom theme which has dependency on Magento/blank

Everything in my theme works good except that whenever I add any error/success messages to the messageManager in my custom module and do a redirect to the custom page displaying a form.

It doesn't display those messages.

**What I Did**

`\Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager` is injected in the constructor

`$this->messageManager->addError('Invalid details provided.');` added this in my controler action's execute method

`$this->_redirect('myorders/uploadorder/index');` doing a redirect to the page where the form is displayed

**What I have already refereed in stack exchange**

[Magento 2 : success messages are not showing](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/104717/magento-2-success-messages-are-not-showing)

[How to use messageManager to show an error after redirect](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/83138/how-to-use-messagemanager-to-show-an-error-after-redirect)

[Magento 2: Ensure Message Manager Messages Show Up After a Redirct](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/93251/magento-2-ensure-message-manager-messages-show-up-after-a-redirct)

Comment: try to set message block element cache  false . the problem because of cache

Comment: Did you use Ajax? or just a normal controller?

Answer (score 3):

From what I can see with what your posting it doesn't seem to be an issue with the functional more the theme or 3rd party extension removing the message block or you have a js conflict which is preventing it

In my case it was a 3rd party application causing a it to reset the message cookie check in chome cookies and see if the response is being set and reset if so it's most likely a module which is causing the message to be unset

Answer (score 0):

In your controller execute action:

```
/** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
$resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
$this->_messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('Some error message.'));

$resultRedirect->setPath('your/module/path');

return $resultRedirect;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 protected $_messageManager;

public function __construct(        
    \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager, 
  ) {   

           $this->messageManager = $messageManager; 
           return parent::__construct($context);

      }

    public function execute()   {

        if(/* set your condition */)
        {

              $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__('Subscriber succesfully  done'));

        }else{

             $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('Already Subscriber'));
        }

        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        $resultRedirect->setPath('/');
        return $resultRedirect;

    }
```